# Float Image Responsive when resize browser

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

i create float image in bottom browser..
but i want, when resize my browser, this float image always show..

**this screenshot when maximaze my browser**

[image]

**this screenshot when resize my browser**

This float image has been gone

[image]

**This is my script float image**

```
<div class="ads adunit">
<div class="ads adunit"><style type="text/css">
#floating_banner_bottom {
bottom: 0px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
_position:absolute;
_bottom:expression(document.body.scrollTop+document.body.clientHeight-this.clientHeight);
}
#floating_banner_bottom { margin-bottom: 0px; bottom: 0 }
#floating_banner_bottom div.close {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
</style>

<div id="floating_banner_bottom" style="z-index: 999; top: 515px;">

<div class="close">
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('floating_banner_bottom').style.display='none';return false;">
<img src="images/PhoXo2.png" border="0"></a>
</div>

<center>
<table><tbody><tr>
<td><a href="#" data-ajax="false" rel="nofollow" ><img src="images/ads/default/pencarian_beforeloop.jpg" width="100%" height="60"></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</center>
</div></div>
</div>
```

Help me, Thank's

Answer (score 0):

In your css try this one

sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owguy80q/) the image is always centered at the bottom.

**CSS**

```
#floating_banner_bottom {
bottom: 0px;
position: fixed; //remove
position: absolute; // add
z-index: 100;
left: 0px; // change to left: 50%;
margin-left: -50%; // add
width: 100%; 
text-align: center;
_position:absolute; //remove
_bottom:expression(document.body.scrollTop+document.body.clientHeight-this.clientHeight); // remove
}
```

Comment: I try put demo in jsfiddle to my web this image not show
you can see this > www.tingali.com

Answer (score 0):

Use css as per screen size

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
}
```